# Cannot Hide Google Map if custom field is blank

Tags: custom-field, google-maps

I am using the following to display google maps using hotel_address custom field.

```
<iframe width="440" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php the_field('hotel_address'); ?>&amp;iwloc=&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small>
```

And it is working fine, getting hotel address and displaying a map, however I would like to hide this is hotel_address is blank.

I have tried the following

```
<?php
    $map = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hotel_address', true);
    if ( $map ) {
        echo '<iframe width="440" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q="'.$map.'"&amp;iwloc=&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small>';
        echo '';
    }
?>
```

And can confirm that $map is picking up the address by using echo $map however it just shows a blank box without any map.

Any ideas?
Richard

Comment: does `if($map !="")` work? and does the 1st code block show a map and the second fail to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
if ( $map && $map != "" )
```

as you set the variable, but it can also contain an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

To find out the content of a variable you should prefer `var_dump()` over `echo` as it gives you the type and the content of a variable.

You could also try to typecast your variable to a boolean value, because an empty string will also evaluate to `true` in an simple if, but `var_dump((bool) "");`will give you `false`.

```
if( (bool)$map) {
```

Answer (score 0):

$map = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hotel_address', true);

can return empty value, first need to var_dump($map) to make sure the hotel_address is working

if $map is empty then make sure, $post->ID is working.

Try this

```
if( !empty( $map )) {
```

or try this

```
$map = get_the_field('hotel_address');
echo (!empty($map)) ? '<iframe width="440" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q='.$map.'&amp;iwloc=&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small>' : '';
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: $map = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hotel_address', true); can return empty value, first need to var_dump($map) to make sure the hotel_address is working, if $map is empty then make sure, $post->ID is working.

Comment: Please update your *answer*; comments are hidden from our search engine.

Comment: All right toscho

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code. It may work for you

```
<?php
    $map = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hotel_address', true);
    if (isset($map) && !empty($map)) {
        echo '<iframe width="440" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q="'.$map.'"&amp;iwloc=&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small>';
        echo '';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make attension if this code is not work then do first :

Please add `wp_reset_query();` after while loop you taken before this code, and try this

```
$map = CFS()->get('hotel_address'); 

if($map){

//  show map 

}
```